# Byte string to string from binary file

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, blockchain

I was parsing a binary file using python..I got the first few values correctly from the file. But when I try to read a hash string which is 32 bytes I am getting a wrong output

output ( 32 bit is not posted here )

```
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00
```

What type of encoding Is the above text ?

How can parse it right to string ?

Comment: Your string has only 10 bytes.

Comment: the `b` signifies a binary string, and the `\x00` is escaped hexadecimal coding. `00` can be replaced with the hex value of the byte you wish to use. `John` would be encoded as `b'\x4A\x6F\x68\x6E'`

Comment: @Daniel I didn't post the whole string here...

Comment: @Bert I am trying to read data from a .dat file tho.. Those 32 bits are from the film.. what you are saying is I am reading the wrong part ????

Comment: "What type of encoding Is the above text ?" - it's _impossible_ to guess as these are merely some bytes.

Comment: @ForceBru it's from the block chain.. 32 bytes of previous hash which is a sha 256 hash

Answer (score 1):

This is only the representation of your string. In memory, you have the bytes you want.

```
>>> data = b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
>>> len(data) # length of data
10
>>> data[0] # value of first byte
0
```

As I get from the comments, the intended output is the value of the bytes:

```
>>> ' '.join(map(str, data))
'0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0'
```

Comment: how do I get the value of the 32 bytes ?

Comment: 32 bytes data is a hash... it's showing as bytes,, I want the real value from the bytes @Daniel

Comment: What is the real value? Don't understand, what you really want.

Comment: http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-DaJcdsyqQSs/UsiTXNHP-0I/AAAAAAAATC0/kiFRowh-J18/s1600/blockchain.png

Comment: .  The previous hash which is a sha 256 digest (uint_8) .. I think the value is need is 32 zeros @Daniel

Comment: And you have at least 10 zeros. So again, I don't see, where's your problem is.

Comment: How to print 10 zeros from that byte  as a single string ? @Daniel

Comment: Exactly this was my question to you: How should the output look like?